# How to get navbar to appear on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's an example: https://www.waveapps.com/pro-network/

As you begin to scroll the nav-bar will disappear and then re-appear. How might I achieve something like this?

```
I am using Rails as my framework, along with Twitter Bootstrap.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can set an event handler for the scroll event and use the `scrollTop()` function to get the current scroll position.

Here's a tutorial: http://www.sutanaryan.com/how-to-create-fixed-menu-when-scrolling-page-with-css-and-jquery/